# PHP PDO fetch behaviour

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Let's say the table **table** contains many records and I query a select statement with some conditions, in this case, **foo=1**. After fetching a record, I'll use this record to do something which spends so much time, and I use **sleep(2)** to make it understand easily.

```
$stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo=1');
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    //do sth
    sleep(2);
}
```

After fetching the *first row*, if there is other session updating the table, for example, update the *third row* (let's assume the original **foo** of third row is 1) and set foo=0, will the above script still retrieve the *third row*? I'm wondering what the fetch function does behind the code.

Comment: No, because the query is executed above the while, not IN the while itself. The loop just loops through the resultset received from the query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when you execute a query it runs to completion, then the results are sent to your database driver, in this case PDO, for consumption.

Even when you're using techniques to get the data sequentially, like cursors or streaming rowsets, the effect is the same. The result of your query will not be impacted by subsequent statements.

Consider everything you retrieve from PDO to be a snapshot taken at a singular point in time.